# useMemo being called without any change in dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I am using React 17 and trying to move some redux data to react query.

One of the common functionality in redux is to massage the api data and store it for all the consumers.

I am trying to replicate the same functionality via react query. If the api call is successful the 1st time - I want to massage the data returned by the api and save it in useMemo

```
function massageCategoriesData(data){
// ...some computation here...
}

const useDataCategories = () => {
  const query = useQuery(
    ['categories'],
    () => api.fetchCategories(),
    { staleTime: Infinity, cacheTime: Infinity },
  );

  const { data, isSuccess } = query;

  const finalData = useMemo(() => {
    if (isSuccess) {
      return massageCategoriesData(data);
    }
    return null;
  }, [query.isSuccess]);

  return {
    query,
    data: finalData,
  };
};
```

But the problem is, when I'm calling useDataCategories from components which are getting unmounted and mounted again and again - the massaging is happening everytime and useMemo is not working..

I tried to read the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) and here's what they say:

> **You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.** In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized values and recalculate them on next render, e.g. to free memory for offscreen components. Write your code so that it still works without useMemo — and then add it to optimize performance.

Please help!
Is the behavior of useMemo dependent on other things as well ?

Comment: If your component is getting unmounted and remounted, it's a new component... useMemo will always rerun.

Comment: verified that using this codesandbox @JustinTaddei
but then how to massage data and store it globally using react query

Answer (score 0):

You would likely want to do that inside the queryFn itself:

```
const useDataCategories = () => {
  const query = useQuery(
    ['categories'],
    async () => {
      const data = await api.fetchCategories()
      return massageCategoriesData(data)
    }
    { staleTime: Infinity, cacheTime: Infinity },
  );
```

I've written in detail about the different approaches and their tradeoffs here: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-data-transformations

Comment: got it, let me try it